# How to add to a read-only 'List' property in class defined using expression body?

Tags: c#, .net

When I run the code below the 'Works' property on TestHelper returns 4 Test items as it should but the 'Fails' property only returns 1 Test item.

Sample Classes:

```
  public class Test {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class TestHelper {
    public TestHelper() {
      AddTest(new Test() { Name = "1" });
    }

    public List<Test> Works { get; } = new List<Test>() {
      new Test(){ Name="0"}
    };

    public List<Test> Fails => new List<Test>() {
      new Test(){ Name="0"}
    };

    public TestHelper AddTest(Test test) {
      Works.Add(test);
      Fails.Add(test);
      return this;
    }

  }
```

Sample Program:

```
  var th = new TestHelper();
  th.AddTest(new Test { Name = "2" });
  th.Works.Add(new Test { Name = "3" });
  th.Fails.Add(new Test { Name = "4" });

  var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(th);
```

Json Results:

```
{
  "Works":[{"Name":"0"},{"Name":"1"},{"Name":"2"},{"Name":"3"}],
  "Fails":[{"Name":"0"}]
}
```

Both the 'Works' & 'Fails' look to be defined as read-only List properties of Test.

Why does one definition method work and not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Works` is a read-only auto-implemented property with a default value, equivalent to this:

```
private List<Test> _works = new List<Test>() { new Test() { Name="0" } };
public List<Test> Works { get { return _works; } }
```

The value of `Works` is initialized once, when it is created. You are subsequently making modifications to the list by adding values - note that the *property* is read-only, not the `List` that it contains.

By contrast, `Fails` is a property whose getter returns a newly-created list *every time you get it*. It is equivalent to this:

```
public List<Test> Fails
{
    get
    {
        return new List<Test>() { new Test() { Name = "0" } }; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nlawalker, I just realised that too.